# how can I module I uploaded on Bintray before linked to Jcenter?

Tags: android, android-things, bintray, jcenter

Hello I made a driver(?) of mpu6050 for androidthings and uploaded on bintray
https://dl.bintray.com/mechasolution/androidthings/

It seems like uploaded well cuz I successfully downloaded and reused *.aar library.

I've heard it'll take about a day to be linked to Jcenter, so I need additional code to test before it's linked.

In project's build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/mechasolution/AndroidThings/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.3.4'
    }
}
```

In app's build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.mechasolution:mpu6050:0.1@aar'
}
```

below are module's build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'

publish {
    repoName  = 'AndroidThings'
    userOrg = 'mechasolution'
    groupId = 'org.mechasolution'
    artifactId = 'mpu6050'
    publishVersion = '0.1'
    desc = 'mpu6050 driver for AndroidThings provided by mechasolution'
    website = 'https://github.com/mechasolution/mpu6050test'
    issueTracker = "https://github.com/mechasolution/mpu6050test/issues"
    repository = "https://github.com/mechasolution/mpu6050test.git"
}
```

It seem's like correct code but android studio keep gives error

Error:(31, 13) Failed to resolve: org.mechasolution:mpu6050:0.1

does anyone knows what I missed or went wrong?

Comment: For those who looking for AndroidThings contrib driver mpu6050. welcome and try my driver. https://github.com/mechasolution/mpu6050test manual's ready. and soon it'll be linked to jcenter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place your repo under `allprojects` in your root `build.gradle` (not `buildscript`) :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/mechasolution/AndroidThings/" }
    }
}
```

From [Android Studio guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html#top-level) :

> The allprojects block is where you configure the repositories and
>   dependencies used by all modules in your project, such as third-party
>   plugins or libraries. Dependencies that are not required by all the
>   modules in the project should be configured in module-level
>   build.gradle files

Comment: Wow it works. Thanks a lot. I've spent about a day for this. seems like posts I've read are old or the writer gave mis-info. Thanks again.